# MySQL Query that finds duplicates using REGEXP to match on first 7 characters

Tags: mysql, regex

```sql
SELECT nl.legal_name, nl.city, c.description 'Country', it.lei, sec.sym
FROM name_loc             nl
INNER JOIN ident_tbl_tmp  it ON nl.fk_ident_id = it.id 
INNER JOIN sym_exch_cnty sec ON it.fk_sec_id   = sec.id
INNER JOIN countries       c ON nl.fk_cnty_id  = c.id
WHERE legal_name REGEXP '^For'
limit 100;
```

Using the above query will return 500+ rows of data. A partial output is:

Output:

```
+------------------------------------------+--------------+----------------+----------------------+--------------+
| legal_name                               | city         | Country        | lei                  | sym          |
+------------------------------------------+--------------+----------------+----------------------+--------------+
| FOREFRONT GROUP LTD HKD0.01(SUB          | PENDING      | HONG KONG      | NA                   | 2903.HK      |
| FOREFRONT HOLDINGS                       | PENDING      | UNITED STATES  | NA                   | FFHN         |
| FOREIGN & COL INV TR                     | PENDING      | UNITED STATES  | NA                   | FLIVF        |
| Foreign & Colonial Investment Trust      | PENDING      | NEW ZEALAND    | NA                   | FCT.NZ       |
| Foreign & Colonial Investment Trust      | PENDING      | UNITED KINGDOM | NA                   | FRCL.L       |
| Foreign & Colonial Investment Trust PLC  | London       | UNITED KINGDOM | 8VHDVYVI7W11JH2PAC61 | NA           |
| Foreland                                 | PENDING      | SINGAPORE      | NA                   | E1:B0I.SI    |
| Foreland                                 | PENDING      | SINGAPORE      | NA                   | E2:B0I.SI    |
```

I need a query that will return a result when the first 'n' characters match and the countries are the same.

This would be the correct result for matching on the first 7 characters:

```
+------------------------------------------+--------------+----------------+----------------------+--------------+
| legal_name                               | city         | Country        | lei                  | sym          |
+------------------------------------------+--------------+----------------+----------------------+--------------+
| Foreign & Colonial Investment Trust      | PENDING      | UNITED KINGDOM | NA                   | FRCL.L       |
| Foreign & Colonial Investment Trust PLC  | London       | UNITED KINGDOM | 8VHDVYVI7W11JH2PAC61 | NA           |
| Foreland                                 | PENDING      | SINGAPORE      | NA                   | E1:B0I.SI    |
| Foreland                                 | PENDING      | SINGAPORE      | NA                   | E2:B0I.SI    |
```

This would be the correct result for matching on the first 14 characters:

```
+------------------------------------------+--------------+----------------+----------------------+--------------+
| legal_name                               | city         | Country        | lei                  | sym          |
+------------------------------------------+--------------+----------------+----------------------+--------------+
| Foreign & Colonial Investment Trust      | PENDING      | UNITED KINGDOM | NA                   | FRCL.L       |
| Foreign & Colonial Investment Trust PLC  | London       | UNITED KINGDOM | 8VHDVYVI7W11JH2PAC61 | NA           |
```

I have tried various sub-queries but no luck. I am think that I might need a function or procedure but I am not sure.

Comment: I'm confused as to how "Foreign & Colonial..." matches "Foreland" in the first 7 characters?

Comment: I'm sorry for not being more concise, the first 7 characters in "Foreign & Colonial..." are "Foreign" so both rows have a duplicate name based on just the first seven chars in legal_name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply `GROUP BY Country, LEFT(legal_name, 7)`. This will ensure that you only get a single row of output for every combination of country and name prefix. You have no influence over which row that will be. You could even add a column `COUNT(*) AS number_of_duplicates` if you want to keep track of the number of original rows.

Comment: Thank you, this is not exactly what I was looking for but it will work. One question, how can I limit the select (the rows which are printed) to only those where "COUNT(*) AS number_of_duplicates" is greater than 1? I tried "SELECT if(count(*) >= 2, nl.legal_name, nl.city, c.description 'Country', it.lei, sec.sym, COUNT(*) AS number_of_duplicates, '')"  but got an error message. Thanks.

Comment: @John: Restructions using aggregate functions go with `HAVING`. So you either write `HAVING number_of_duplicates > 1` or `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`.